# create view and perform an addition from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

Creating view and add the column value from multiple tables. is that possible?

```
Users:
ID | FIRST NAME | LASTNAME |
1  | Mark       | Lupez    |
2  | James      | Yap      |

table1:
USER_ID | SCORE | GOAL |
   1    |   7   |   9  |
   2    |   4   |   6  |



table2:
USER_ID | SCORE | GOAL |
   1    |   4   |   9  |
   2    |   7   |   3  |


table3:
USER_ID | SCORE | GOAL |
   1    |   2   |   3  |
   2    |   3   |   2  |
```

I want to add

> table1.score, table2.score, table3.score

where the

> table1.user_id, table2.user_id, table3.user_id

are equals to the ID column of the Users table.

so the query results that created by view table is look like this...

```
LASTNAME  |  FIRST NAME  |  SCORE  | GOAL  |
Lupez     |  Mark        |  13     | 21    |
Yap       |  James       |  14     | 11    |
```

I am new in mysql so my knowledge about mysql syntax is absolutely basic. adding from multiple tables is a very huge problem for me...

Comment: firstly, why have you got 3 separate tables all with the same columns? That looks like a bad design to me.

Comment: oh sorry. I do that in a purpose but I glad to know more how to make that design better,,,..

Comment: well you should probably combine them all into one table. If there's some difference between them (they represent a different type of match, perhaps) then you could add another status column to represent the difference. More generally you should google about the principles of database normalisation in order to create good relational designs and avoid redundancy. Good design will remove a lot of problems later when trying to write queries

Comment: Thanks for your help to make my design better..I Appreciated that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I make some query from your sample data try this query

(I don't know why you split to 3 tables I think it's not a good design)

```
    SELECT u.ID
    ,u.LastName
    ,u.FirstName
    ,result.SCORE
    ,result.GOAL
FROM Users u 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT q.USER_ID ,SUM(q.SCORE) AS 'score' , SUM(q.GOAL) AS 'goal' 
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.USER_ID,t1.SCORE,t1.GOAL
        FROM table1 t1
        UNION
        SELECT t2.USER_ID ,t2.SCORE,t2.GOAL
        FROM table2 t2
        UNION
        SELECT t3.USER_ID,t3.SCORE,t3.GOAL
        FROM table3 t3
    ) q
    GROUP BY q.USER_ID 
) result 
ON result.USER_ID = u.ID
```

Comment: Sorry for that.. since i'm a newbie in mysql, I decided to split that table so that I can easily understand when I Invoking  a queries....

Comment: I tried your code and I got this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[USER_ID] ,SUM(SCORE) [SCORE] , SUM(GOAL) [GOAL]`

Comment: Oh... it's replace it's with you column and delete [SCORE] , [GOAL]  I write query on difference DBMS but it's same meaning with MySQL ( meaning for my code that have error like this find SUM(column_name) then set alias name)

Comment: thank you.. I accepted your answer not only because you are correct, it is because you help me to make my design good... by the way I changed my design what you suggested... thanks a lot man...